# how to send email in CodeIgniter on live server

Tags: codeigniter, email

In my codeIgniter project , i want to send email, i am using following mail function but its not working.please help me.
Controller code follows:

```
public function mail() {
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
    $toEmail = "suraj@paarva.in";
    $mailHeaders = "From: " . $_POST["userName"] . "<br> Email ID:". $_POST["userEmail"] ."\r\n";
    if(mail($toEmail, $_POST["Mobile"], $_POST["message"], $mailHeaders)) {

    print "<p class='alert alert-success'>Mail Sent.</p>";
    } else {
    print "<p class='alert alert-danger'>Problem in Sending Mail.</p>";
    }

    }
```

Comment: What is the error comes??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
 $config = Array(        
                 'mailtype' => 'html',
                  'charset'  => 'utf-8',
                  'priority' => '1'
        );
        $this->load->library('email',$config); 
         $message = '<html><body>';
         $message .= '<p>Hello admin,</p>';
       
         $from_email = $this->input->post('userEmail'); 
         $to_email = "suraj@paarva.in"; 
         $this->email->from($from_email, 'Abra'); 
         $this->email->to($to_email);
         $this->email->subject('Subject'); 
         $this->email->message($message); 
       
         //Send mail 
         if($this->email->send()) {
               echo "ok";
}
         else {
         echo "no";
         
 }
```

This is a simple code for sending email. When you are using live server from email address or to email address any one of these should be domain mail address.

Answer (score 1):

May be you connect to wrong smtp server. Can you try that:

[image: please try this]

Comment: I'm using yandex smtp and it is working well. Please check my code: https://github.com/nixarsoft/native-php-session-codeigniter/blob/master/application/helpers/various_helper.php

Answer (score 0):

> Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection refused)

It's possible that your server's IP address is blacklisted by Google due to previous spamming attempts... Is it a shared hosting account? A cloud hosting account? Etc? All those are susseptable to stuff like this.